# How to run Android-x86 with a resolution of 3840*2160 inside VMWare

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, android-x86

I am using VMWare Workstation Player on a Smart Table under Windows and would like to get Android-x86 running there at `3840x2160` resolution.

By default, this is simply not possible. At `1152x864` is the highest resolution that the VM returns me, I could set if I use `vga=ask`.

I used the following link as a guide:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003

That is I have expanded the .vmx file of the VM and entered the following accordingly:

```
svga.vramSize = 33177600
svga.maxWidth = 3840
svga.maxHeight = 2160
```

Permanent change it inside the VM could be done like as example:

If the android system is started press `Alt+F1`.

type in

```
mkdir /mnt/sda
mount /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/sda
vi /mnt/sda/grub/menu.lst
```

press `i` to edit, replace quiet to nomodeset xforcevesa if you have not done it until now. Because you can make sure, that it will boot. At the end of the line add `UVESA_MODE=yourdesiredresolution` as example `UVESA_MODE=1280x720`

press `Esc` to return read-mode press `:w` then press `Enter` press `:q` then press `Enter` type `reboot` then press `Enter`

Okay, that was just an example. When booting up, you can press `e` accordingly when booting, then `e` again and set it individually for this boot process. As mentioned at the beginning with `vga=ask` you can display what should be supported. Accordingly, I would have to configure something else, since the change of the `.vmx` has not provided any added value.

Does anyone have experience with this and could help? Thanks in advance!